# how to use preventDefault() While passing variable in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My React app's page is reloading on onClick, I'm passing a variable to the function and i want my page not to refresh.

so that i used (a.e){e.preventDefault(); //code to use a//} . My compiler throwing error=  'e' is not defined. and if I dot's define e as parameter, it still giving me the sam error. Someone Please Help

```
const f=(a)=>{ let newText=text.concat(" "+a); setText(newText) } 
<button className='btn btn-dark mx-2' onClick={()=>{f( var_f)}}>F</button>
```

Comment: Can you share a bit more of your code?

Comment: `onClick={(e) => myFunction(e, myVariable)}`

Comment: The first parameter is the event object. So, try this: `yourFunction(ev, abc) { ev. preventDefault(); /* use abc variable here*/};`. Or, please use arrow-function style as noted by @SalminSkenderovic in above comment.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code there.

Comment: const f=(a)=>{ 
  let newText=text.concat(" "+a);
  setText(newText)
  
}
<button className='btn btn-dark mx-2' onClick={()=>{f( var_f)}}>F</button>

Comment: So, onClick may become like so: `onClick={ev => f(ev, var_f)}`. And function definition may become like this: `const f = (ev, a) => { ev.preventDefault(); .....};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also do it like this

```
  const handleChange = (variable) => (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(variable);
  };

  onClick={handleChange("whatever")}
```